# Return rows in common with another user in SQL (Collaborative Filtering)

Tags: mysql, sql, collaborative-filtering

I'm trying to build a basic collaborative filtering recommendation system using MySQL. I have a user rating table like this:

```
    user_id movie_id rating
1   131     342      3      <<< User 131 has rated movie 342 
2   131     312      5      <<< and also 312
3   122     312      4  
4   213     342      5
5   141     342      5      <<< User 141 has rated 342
6   141     312      4      <<< and also 312 (2 movies in common) 
7   141     323      3
```

So I'm trying to find similar users to 131. I want to return the users who have at least two movies in common and the ratings are above 3. So it should return rows 5 and 6 (as shown above).

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * from user_ratings
WHERE rating >= 3
AND movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id from user_rating WHERE user_id = 131)
AND user_id != 131
```

This returns:

```
    user_id movie_id rating
3   122     312      4     <<< Don't want these two
4   213     342      5     <<<
5   141     342      5     
6   141     312      4
```

It returns the movies that users have in common with 131, but I need it to only show the users who have at least two items in common. How could I do this? I'm unsure of how to proceed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the `user_id`s that have more or equal number of movies as `user_id = 131` with `rating > 3`. Then use `IN` in the `WHERE` clause to get the additional data:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e41ed/1/0)

```
SELECT *
FROM user_ratings
WHERE
    user_id IN(
        SELECT user_id
        FROM user_ratings 
        WHERE
            movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id FROM user_ratings WHERE user_id = 131)
            AND rating > 3
        GROUP BY user_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_ratings WHERE user_id = 131)
    )
    AND rating > 3
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join on `movie_id` to get a list of user_ids that have rated at least 2 of the same movies as user 131 at a rating of 4 or higher:

```
select ur2.user_id
from user_ratings ur1
join user_ratings ur2 
    on ur2.movie_id = ur1.movie_id
    and ur2.user_id <> ur1.user_id
where ur1.user_id = 131
    and ur2.rating > 3
group by ur2.user_id
having count(*) >= 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06b56/4